# How can I create test user for application page?

Tags: facebook, testing

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users

I read above page, yet I could not get how to do.
I am preparing application with sandbox mode till it has completed.
But I want to let the people in charge available to access on this application.
Could you please let me know how can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add people as a "Tester".  Go to your list of apps:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Choose the app you care about.  In the "Roles" section, add the person in charge as a Tester.  A Tester can use the app even when it's in sandbox mode.

Here are what all the different roles mean: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/